# symbols not found with zlib functions

Tags: c, symbols, zlib

As from title, when compiling

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <zlib.h>

int main(){

    char *infilename = "triples.txt.gz";
    char *outfilename = "out_test.txt";
    gzFile infile = gzopen(infilename, "rb");
    FILE *outfile = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
    if (!infile || !outfile) return -1;

    char buffer[128];
    int num_read = 0;
    num_read = gzread(infile, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 
    while (num_read > 0) {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, num_read, outfile);
    }

    gzclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the message

```sh
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gzclose", referenced from:
      _main in ccfPmLqz.o
  "_gzopen", referenced from:
      _main in ccfPmLqz.o
  "_gzread", referenced from:
      _main in ccfPmLqz.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am having some troubles figuring out what it is saying. zlib seems to be installed as while adapting the code I had some errors regarding specific zlib functions (like not enough arguments for gzopen).

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: Looks like you are not *linking* with the `zlib` library

Comment: To the point, are you adding `-lz` when compiling/linking?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `gcc -o c_test sometest.c`
How can I solve the linking problem? fairly new to C as you can see

Comment: @L.Scott see my previous comment

Comment: @L.Scott add compile method to question.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't link zlib when you compiled. Assuming zlib is in the standard path, you need to compile as

```
gcc -lz -o c_test sometest.c
```